# Toggle switch validation in Angular JS

Tags: forms, validation, angular5, togglebutton

Hi I am trying to validate toggle switch in Angular 5. If the user selects off then i want to display error message. But when user clicks on submit button(form submission) I am not able to validate if the toggle is off. In below step I want to validate on submit button.

```
  <form *ngIf="formResetToggle" class="form-horizontal" name="permissionEditorForm" #f="ngForm" novalidate
     (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid ? savePermission(selectedUserRole.value,selectedScopeName.value) :
    (!userrole.valid && !scopename.valid && showErrorAlert('Please enter mandatory fields'));">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
         <label class="control-label col-md-2"for="allowdeny">Allow/Deny</label>
                 <div class="col-md-10">
                       <ui-switch checked size="small" [(ngModel)]="permissionEdit.isallowed" name="isallowed" id="isallowed"></ui-switch>
                            <span *ngIf="IsAllowed" class="errorMessage">
                                                Is Allowed should be true!
                            </span>

                 </div>
   </div>
  </form>
```

In the above code, If I do something

```
(ngSubmit)="f.form.valid ? savePermission(selectedUserRole.value,selectedScopeName.value) :
(!userrole.valid && !scopename.valid && !isallowed.valid && showErrorAlert('Please enter mandatory fields'));"
```

then I get error in  !isallowed.valid. The error message says cannot read property of undefined valid. can someone help me to make above validation works? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use safe Navigation operator '?' Ex:(ngSubmit)="f.form?.valid"

Comment: hi Vignesh. the problem is if i make toggle button off then also form will show valid.   <h1>{{f.valid}}</h1>

Comment: You can safe Navigation Operator in expression also  {{f?.valid}}  https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax